# Indexing internal Angular site with Elastic Search

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch

I have an intranet site built on AngularJS 1.x.

The problem I'm trying to solve is to:
1. Index all of the pages in this site
2. Provide search using ElasticSearch

The issues I'm running into is:
I'm not sure how to produce this index to feed into ElasticSearch

I tried CURL but CURL does not interpret the AngularJS program and therefore does not see the content on the partial HTML pages.

Guidance very much appreciated.